# Increasing distance between objects in relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a relative layout for my android app. It is a SurfaceView overlapped with a few images. I had to use relative layout for the camera over lay features. It is currently shown like in the image below:
[image]

The top red long rectangular bars are actually two short rectangle images. I would like to increase the distance between the two images so that they look like two individual rectangles. Is it possible to increase the distance in a relative layout?

If I position two red bars, one on top of the other, is it possible to increase the distance between the two?

Comment: are you talking about the red rectangles? Elaborate some more if you can. It is hard to tell what you are asking.

Comment: @Tim yes I referring to the red rectangular bars. The relative layout parameters allow me to specify only the relative positions. I would like to increase the distance between two rectangular bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a margin between the views and that's it ...

Answer (score 0):

I was reading through the Android developer's page carefully. This [page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_marginBottom) explains how to set margins on the layout